# Mounting UUID=xxx on /sysroot failed: No Such device - Occurs after linux kernel install

Tags: boot, linux-kernel, kernel-panic, alpine-linux

After attempting to install a built kernel and rebooting I am receiving the error:

> mount: mounting UUID=59c56381-e5ec-4a8b-8c2e-f9c6a66d524c on /sysroot failed: No such device

Why is this happening? How can I fix this to boot correctly?

**About System**

- Alpine Linux 3.12_alpha20200319 (edge) -- Alpine Linux Virtual
- Kernel 5.4.31-0-virt
- Running inside VirtualBox

**Kernel Build Steps**

```
wget https://mirrors.edge.kernel/pub/linux/kernel/v5.x/linux-5.4.30.tar.xz
tar -xf linux-5.4.30.tar.xz
cp /boot/config-virt /home/name/build/.config
make -C /home/name/linux-5.4.30 O=/home/name/build listnewconfig
make -j4 -C /home/name/linux-5.4.30 O=/home/name/build
cd /home/name/build
make modules_install
```

The following steps I am uncertain about:

```
cp System.map /boot/System.map-virt
cp arch/x86_64/boot/bzImage /boot/vmlinuz-virt
cp .config /boot/config-virt
```

*I don't run `make install` because it passes arch/x86/boot/bzImage. Because of this, I am GUESSING it is installing 32-bit and 64-bit. So I am trying to install manually instead.*

My extlinux.conf file:

```
DEFAULT menu.c32
PROMPT 0
MENU TITLE Alpine/Linux Boot Menu
MENU HIDDEN
MENU AUTOBOOT Alpine will be booted automatically in # seconds
TIMEOUT 30
LABEL virt
  MENU LABEL linux virt
  LINUX vmlinuz-virt
  INITRD initramfs-virt
  APPEND root=UUID=59c56381-e5ec-4a8b-8c2e-f9c6a66d524c moudles=sd-mod,usb-storage,ext4 quiet rootfstype=ext4

MENU SEPARATOR
```

**Attempts at fixing**

(All of below still result in the same error)

- Running `mkinitfs` in `/` directory before reboot
- Running `extlinux --install /boot`
- Running `make install` in the build directory instead and chaning the extlinux.conf line `LINUX vmlinuz-virt` to `LINUX vmlinuz`
- Tried switching VirtualBox storage controllers to AHCI, virtio-scsi and PIIX4.

**May be helpful:**

I checked the UUID specified in the error and extlinux.conf. It identifies /dev/sda3. However when I enter the emergency recovery shell after the failed boot and check the /dev directory it is not present. No clue why.

lsmod shows no modules loaded. I assume this shouldn't be happening.

If I continue boot by typing `exit` I get the kernel panic[image: Kernel Panic Screenshot]

**Files**

.config - https://github.com/alpinelinux/aports/blob/master/main/linux-lts/config-virt.x86_64

extlinux.conf - https://pastebin.com/QMkePsqS

mkinitfs.conf - https://pastebin.com/rksn7GcN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the post,

> lsmod shows no modules loaded. I assume this shouldn't be happening

the problem was because modules were not being loaded into the kernel. The current version of the kernel running was 5.4.31-0-virt wand the version being built was 5.4.30. The modules being installed were being placed into the `/lib/modules/5.4.30` directory. This caused the initial ram disk (initramfs) to be built without the correct modules for the kernel and hence not loaded on boot.

To fix this, after installing the kernel modules when building the initramfs the following command should be used instead:

`mkinitfs -o /boot/initramfs-virt 5.4.30`

This command includes the installed modules for the 5.4.30 kernel in the initramfs instead of defaulting to the `uname -r` version (in this case 5.4.31-0-virt). The kernel is then able to load the modules -> read the disks -> boot from the required disk.